# Progress bar render on form submit | Complete on data response

Tags: javascript, forms, progress-bar

I am installing a search bar, and I want it to appear when the form is submitted, and complete/dissapear when the response is returned. Any idea on how to do so? I am working with the bootstrap progress bar

```
<div class="progress" style="height: 5px;">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="color:#EB7051;" style="background-color: #ffffff" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

I know this is HTML, but would I have to do anything with my fetch or POST request? That relevant code is below:

```
let progress = 0;
        const maxTime = 5000; // 5 seconds
        let interval = null;


    // onclick or the event that start the call
    interval = setInterval(() => {
    progress = progress >= 100 ? 100 : progress + 1
    document.getElementById('myprogress').style.width = `${progress}%`
    
    // end interval and wait at 100%
    if(progress == 100) clearInterval(interval);
        }, maxTime/100)
    document.getElementById('loadingcontainer').style.display = "none"


        function searchIt() {

            let form = document.querySelector('form')
            console.log(form)

            form.addEventListener('submit', async(e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                let urlIN = form.url.value
                let url = encodeURIComponent(urlIN)
                console.log(url)
                try {
                    const data = await fetch('/', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            url: url
                        })


                    }).then(res => {
                        document.open()
                        res.text().then(function(text) {
                            document.write(text)
                            // Hide the progressbar, stop the timer and reset progress
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        progress = 0;
                        document.getElementById('myprogress').style.width = "0%"
                        document.getElementById('loadingcontainer').style.display = "";
                  
                        });

                    })


                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                }

            })

            

        }
```

[image]

Progress-bar:

```
    .progress-bar {
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            color: rgb(197, 90, 28);
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
        }

    </style>




<div id="loadingcontainer">
<div class="progress" style="height: 5px;">
    <div id="myprogress" class="progress-bar" style="color:#EB7051;" style="background-color: #ffffff" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you downloading anything big? How long does it take to download?

Comment: @MichaelBauer Not downloading anything. It takes anywhere from 5-10 seconds to return a response from my backend. Just want to be able to show the user that a response is being generated

Comment: May still recommend a spinner, even though I said that a progress bar is only useful after 5 or so seconds. Only because you'll then need to hook into the progress events, which Fetch doesn't seem to have. I know using Axios will be a solution to this, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936028/progress-bar-with-axios

Comment: @MichaelBauer Even if it stops after 5 seconds before completing, that's fine. Just trying to hit a particular UI

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a spinner instead of a loading bar unless if you're downloading something that takes more than say 5 seconds to download. The reason is that getting hooking the progress bar up to the downloaded chunks won't be worth the effort.

The steps are:

1. Just before as you send out the request (maybe before or asynchronously after) you display the spinner/progressbar.
2. Then as your download completes, you'll remove the spinner/progressbar

```js
// --- Set somewhere else but within scope
const url = "some url";
let progress = 0;
const maxTime = 5000; // 5 seconds
let interval = null;

// onclick or the event that start the call
interval = setInterval(() => {
    progress = progress >= 100 ? 100 : progress + 1
    document.getElementById('myprogress').style.width = `${progress}%`
    
    // end interval and wait at 100%
    if(progress == 100) clearInterval(interval);
}, maxTime/100)
document.getElementById('loadingcontainer').style.display = "none"

const data = fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        url: url
    })
 }).then(res => {
    document.open()
    res.text().then(function(text) {
        document.write("done")
        // Hide the progressbar, stop the timer and reset progress
        clearInterval(interval);
        progress = 0;
        document.getElementById('myprogress').style.width = "0%"
        document.getElementById('loadingcontainer').style.display = "";
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="loadingcontainer" >
  <div class="progress">
     <div id="myprogress" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 10%" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"> 
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Naturally the code above doesn't run because of the fetch but it should give you an idea.

Comment: I am not using jQuery. Would it matter?

Comment: Not too much, I can modify it to help, but effectively replace the lines .hide() and .show() with `document.getElementById('loadingcontainer').style.display = "none" ` to hide it and set it to "block" or nothing to display it.

Comment: I suspect you may actually have jQuery because you say you have bootstrap installed, which has a dependency on it.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I really need the progress bar. Even if it stops after 5 seconds before completing, that's fine. Just trying to hit a particular UI – let me update the OP with a mockup

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: It also does not need to show accurate progress. Even if it moves a certain pace, and then pauses, until the request completes and the bar disappears, that is a fine approach

Comment: Ex: moves for 5 seconds, and then stops, waits for request to complete, and then finishes

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Since you're using the bootstrap progressbar and may just simulate loading, then you can use something like `setInteval` to have a callback that increment the progress. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks man. I just gave it a shot and it renders, but only shows up after data is returned. Not while it is waiting for the data. Any advice? I will update my code to show more. Any advice helps.

Comment: From the looks of your code there are 2 parts that need tweaking. The first is that you're setting 'loadingcontainer' display to 'none' at the start, and showing it at the end, you need to switch those around. The section of code above `function searchIt()` and below the first 3 lines should be within the `form.addEventListener` callback.

Comment: Thank you so much !! Really appreciate all the help