# Axios onUploadProgress only fires once on my machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

If I use this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v70kou59/1/ everything works as expected

```
(function () {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    document.getElementById('upload').onclick = function () {
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('foo', 'bar');
      data.append('file', document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
      var config = {
        onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
          var percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
          console.log(percentCompleted)
        }
      };
      axios.put('/upload/server', data, config)
        .then(function (res) {
          output.className = 'container';
          output.innerHTML = res.data;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          output.className = 'container text-danger';
          output.innerHTML = err.message;
        });
    };
  })();
```

But if I download the axios examples repo and install the necessary dependencies the callback function, onUploadProgress no longer works as expected. It only fires onUploadProgress once with "100".
https://github.com/axios/axios/tree/master/examples

Could this be my version of node? It seems like it must be my machine.

Comment: Did you try with a big enough file? Maybe the data doesn't get chunked the same way locally and instantly completes the upload?

Comment: Yeah I believe this was the issue. Jpegs are too small and it was completing instantly. My confusion comes from that jfiddle example because in that example the progress is gradual and not instant even with jpegs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've had exact issue. One of the reason(it was the case with me) could be, your network is too fast to trigger the `progressEvent` multiple times.

To simulate this, slow down your network on Network tab of your Browser.

`Slow 3G` setting worked for me on Google Chrome/New Edge(dev release) browser.

Refer the image:

[image]

PS: I know this is too late to answer this. But others might find it helpful when they land here.

Comment: is there a way to enforce the split even on speed netwrok?

Answer (score -3):

Because the new version changed.

[image]

So you have to call *progress* instead of onUploadProgress

```
 static uploadImageFile(authId, userinfo, file, callback) {
        let url = AppConfig.domain + '/api/CoreUploads/uploadImg';
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('realm', userinfo.realm);
        formData.append('fileurl', `users/${userinfo.id}/`);
        formData.append('cropData', "");
        formData.append('autoid', true);
        formData.append('image', file);

        return axios.post(url, formData, {
            timeout: 1000000,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': authId,
                'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            progress: function (progressEvent) {
                let percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
                callback(percentCompleted);
            }
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);

        });
    }
```

Comment: There is no method called progress: () => {}

Comment: see my screenshot above, that shows you the source code of progress method

Comment: onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {}  is what works.

Comment: I tested this and is not working, just use ```onUploadProgress```

Comment: In case anyone is confused by this, the explanation is that the **old** way of doing it was via the `progress` method. Now it's `onUploadProgress`. Most people will want the latter unless they are using a very, very old version of axios. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55330472/1994235 for more details.